# \r is removed when I return a string from web service to client (C#)

Tags: .net, web-services

I am calling a web method (C#) which accepts a string and returns a string. The string returned by web method has got \r\n, but at the client the string has got only \n. seems like \r was removed while transferring data from service to client.
Can any one please tell what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Line breaks in Javascript are represented by the single new line character "\n", not the combination of new line and carriage return.